# Unable to solve error showing as state undefined in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, my objective is to make protective routes and went through the link https://codesandbox.io/s/github/browniefed/tmp/tree/reactRouterProtectedRoute/ but in my code locally I'm getting an error like state is not defined. I couldn't able to figure it out where I'm doing wrong.

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, loggedIn, path, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    path={path}
    {...rest} render={props => {

      // authorised so return component
      return loggedIn ? (<Component {...props} />) : (<Redirect to={{
        pathname: "/Signin",
        state: {
          prevLocation: path,
          error: "You need to login first!",
        },
      }}

      />)
    }} />
)
```

I'm getting error as shown in below snapshot:

[image: snap]

Can anyone help me in solving this error?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your object restructuring. It should look like `const {state: {}} = this.props.location`

Comment: No, the syntax is right. It defaults to `{}` if there is not state when destructring it.

Comment: @devserkan - can you please assist me in this ? I have given in app.js

Comment: How can I produce this error? Your sandbox works for me. I can go through the links, also log in works.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a conditional (based on a signed flag) rendering use their component [official example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Then use the conditional component (Remember to define the "/login" route because it will default to this then the auth is false)

```
<PrivateRoute path="/protected">
    <ProtectedConponent /> 
</PrivateRoute>
```

You can provide `FakeAuth.isAuthenticated` as your own way.

It seem that you want to pass your own state using the redirect component but you should not do that, if you want to pass arguments to the "secure component" do it when you declare it.

```
<PrivateRoute path="/protected">
    <ProtectedConponent custom_prop={"my prop"}/> // < ---- here
</PrivateRoute>
```

Comment: They do not assign the state, they restructure the state from `this.props.location` which comes with `Redirect` or `Link`.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component like this 
=> withRouter(yourComponent);

Comment: Basically It will allow your component to read location values